# Is this Facebook app possible?

Tags: facebook

I want to create a this Facebook app but I don't know if it's possible.

In this FB app users could send through 2 types of images (images with smiles) to their friends' wall. A smile with a tongue out would be more like a "joke" while a smile with sexy lips would mean a more intimate contact.

Comment: Hmm, visual poke. Not quite, but could be...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd like to help you out with at least structuring how you're going to think of an app like this.

First and most importantly, before you start coding familiarize yourself with the [Facebook Platform Guidelines](https://developers.facebook.com/policy/). This is going to be what ensures your app goes up, and stays up.

Second, determine if you are trying to build an Application, Application Tab, or Website. An application and application tab work functionally similarly, but the App Tab can be added to a Page. There's also nothing wrong with developing an Application (standalone on the canvas) which also has an accompanying Tab. A Website is a standalone entity integrated to facebook through authentication, in which you control the entire user experience. Given the details provided here, you'd be better off starting with an Application canvas.

Next, determine where you're going to be hosting this. I recommend Heroku, because they'll provide you with free hosting space and a URL, which is required to set up an app. You can read more about [Facebook integration on Heroku's website](http://www.heroku.com/facebook)

Now, think about what purpose you want your application to serve. You want to make an entertainment application which will either "flirt" or "joke" with your friends. Your messaging might look like:

```
Your friend John sent you a flirty picture.
```

Or

```
Your friend Jill sent you a smile.
```

Really, this is just an extension of poking, so you'll have to keep the verbage in line to get the same desired effect. Or, you could do something like a decision tree and make it more entertaining-- say, something like:

```
        Respond with Joke
Joke <                        Respond with Flirt
        Respond with Flirt  <
                              Respond with Insult
```

Or something along those lines. Make it more engaging than the simple "Click to send a picture!" You'd get some nice organic growth out of that.

Another consideration is what permissions you'll be asking for. You do not want to be overbearing with what you ask for, and even if any have to be at all until an action is required. I leave that up to you to figure out.

Thats about all I can really help you with, short of actually building it out. Think it out. Silly ideas like this have potential to take off.

Comment: I have a general idea of what it's needed but can't quite explain. Do you have an email or other way I can explain this better?

Comment: @JoãoPaulo, just hit me through my FB proxy-- buzzedword@facebook.com